# Kubernetes python pod profiling

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running python pod on Kubernetes and only one main pod keeps restarting.

Memory is increasing continuously so that k8s restart it as implemented liveness, readiness there.

Using flask with python-3.5 & socket.io.

Is there any way i can do profiling on Kubernetes pod without doing code changes using installing any agent or any how. Please let me know.

I am getting Terminated with code 137.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are really using 9 years old Python 3.2?

Comment: yes can't do anything with it i am not developer. i manage infra only so.

Comment: @KlausD. We are using 3.5 sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using GKE right ? 
You should use stackriver monitoring in order to profile, capture, analyze metrics and strackdriver logs in order to understand what's happening.

Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring is the default option, starting with GKE version 1.14. It's really intuitive but some knowledge and understanding of the platform is required. You should be able to create a graph based on memory utilization.

Have a look at the documentation:

- [Stackdriver support for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/)
- [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/)

Comment: thanks for writing answer. already using it but so far no help. tried to use Google Profiler but it's not supporting wall profiling for 3.5 python.

Comment: @HarshManvar, indeed, [stackdriver profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python) requires Python 3.6 or higher for wall.

Comment: @KhalidK yes it's support 3.6 and higher

Answer (score 1):

If you want an open source solution, you can do this with [Robusta](https://docs.robusta.dev/master/catalog/actions/python-troubleshooting.html#python-memory). Disclaimer: I wrote this.

Essentially it injects `tracemalloc` into your pod on demand and sends you the results in Slack. No restart needed.